# What is the difference between different ways of passing a function as an argument to another function?

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing

I have the situation where one function calls one of several possible functions. This seems like a good place to pass a function as a parameter. In this [Quoara answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-pass-a-function-as-an-argument-to-another-function-in-c++-1) by Zubkov there are three ways to do this.

```
int g(int x(int)) { return x(1); }
int g(int (*x)(int)) { return x(1); }
int g(int (&x)(int)) { return x(1); }
...
int f(int n) { return n*2; }
g(f); // all three g's above work the same
```

When should which method be used? What are there differences? I prefer the [simplest approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) so why shouldn't the first way always be used?

For my situation, the function is only called once and I'd like to keep it simple. I have it working with pass by pointer and  I just call it with `g(myFunc)` where `myFunc` is the function that gets called last.

Comment: None of them.  Use a template parameter.

Comment: The first two are completely equivalent. The third is almost the same as the first two, except it requires an lvalue. `g(+f);` works for the first two, but not the third.

Comment: @RaymondChen "The first two are completely equivalent" then in my view the first is obviously the correct choice since it's simpler. Why complicate it with a pointer?

Comment: On the other hand, in `int g(int x(int))`, `x` is a pointer even though it doesn't look like one. The corresponding global declaration `int x(int);` declares a function, not a function pointer.

Comment: [A godbolt link to back up @RaymondChen's claim](https://godbolt.org/z/rZbmAS). Note that the emitted assembly labels `x` as a pointer too.

Comment: Indeed, the original Quora answer said the same thing: "if you write a function taking another function as a parameter, it will be silently adjusted to a function taking a pointer." The original Quora answer also noted that C++ prefers callables over function pointers and gives the same examples as presented in the answers below.

Comment: @RaymondChen: `g(+f)` fails in the third case not because `+f` is not an lvalue, but because `+f` changes `f` from a reference to a pointer (!). `g(*+f)` works just fine.

Comment: @Eric Oops. Was trying to make a function rvalue, but now realized that those things don't exist.

Comment: I was hoping that `std::move(f)` could produce such an rvalue, but it behaves very strangely - asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58252538/102441) to follow up on that.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on L.F.'s comment, it's often better to eschew function pointers entirely, and work in terms of invocable objects (things which define `operator()`). All of the following allow you to do that:

```
#include <type_traits>

// (1) unrestricted template parameter, like <algorithm> uses
template<typename Func>
int g(Func x) { return x(1); }

// (2) restricted template parameter to produce possibly better errors
template<
    typename Func,
    typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<int, Func, int>>
>
int g(Func x) { return std::invoke(x, 1); }

// (3) template-less, trading a reduction in code size for runtime overhead and heap use
int g(std::function<int(int)> x) { return x(1); }
```

Importantly, all of these can be used on lambda functions with captures, unlike any of your options:

```
int y = 2;
int ret = g([y](int v) {
    return y + v;
});
```

Comment: How are these called? Also how are these better?

Comment: They are called in exactly the same way as your signatures above. They're better because they work with lambdas, and other stateful functions. Note that all of `<algorithm>` uses this approach to accept callback functions.

Comment: Ok. To confirm, you don't need to call the templated function with a template identifier? For example you don't need `g<int>(myFunc)` just `g(myFunc)`?

Comment: Correct, the idea is to let the tyoe parameter be inferred

Comment: Would templates still work if you're passing more than one function as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, you would just use a template parameter for each function. Take a look at the `BinaryOp2` overload of [`transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) for an example in the standard library.