# Why is `decltype(static_cast<T>(...))` not always `T`?

Tags: c++, static-cast

For the following code, all but the last assertion passes:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr void assert_static_cast_identity() {
    using T_cast = decltype(static_cast<T>(std::declval<T>()));
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T_cast, T>);
}

int main() {
    assert_static_cast_identity<int>();
    assert_static_cast_identity<int&>();
    assert_static_cast_identity<int&&>();
    // assert_static_cast_identity<int(int)>(); // illegal cast
    assert_static_cast_identity<int (&)(int)>();
    assert_static_cast_identity<int (&&)(int)>(); // static assert fails
}
```

Why is this last assertion failing, and `static_cast<T>` not always returning a `T`?

Comment: I add `T_cast i{1};` I get `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'T_cast' {aka 'int (&)(int)'} from an rvalue of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'`, so for whatever reason `T_cast` is a `int (&)(int)` rather than a `int (&&)(int)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is hard-coded in the definition of `static_cast`:

> **[expr.static.cast]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#1) The result of the expression `static_­cast<T>(v)` is the result
>   of converting the expression `v` to type `T`. **If `T` is an lvalue
>   reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, the result is
>   an lvalue**; if `T` is an rvalue reference to object type, the result is
>   an xvalue; otherwise, the result is a prvalue. The `static_­cast`
>   operator shall not cast away constness.

`decltype` respects the value category of its operand, and produces an lvalue reference for lvalue expressions.

The reasoning may be due to function names themselves always being lvalues, and so an rvalue of a function type cannot appear "in the wild". As such, casting to that type probably makes little sense.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25146508/102441) addresses in more detail _"rvalue[s] of a function type [not] appear[ing] "in the wild""_